# Solving a hyperbolic tangent function for X

Tags: machine-learning, hyperbolic-functions

I've attempted to solve this equation on my own, but... four hours later and here I am. My coworker is attempting to make a machine learning program and he needs to find the value of $x$ in this equation:

\begin{equation}
R = \tanh( \tanh(a+x)z + \tanh(b+x)y + \tanh(c+x)w )
\end{equation}

Where $-1 < R < 1$.

I'm kind of bashing my head against this struggling to figure out how to isolate $x$. I first tried writing the equation out with the knowledge that:

\begin{equation}
\tanh = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}}
\end{equation}

Which resulted in this absolute abomination that is no closer to me actually isolating $x$

\begin{equation}
R = \frac{\exp{\left(\dfrac{z\cdot e^{2a+2x}-z}{e^{2a+2x}+1} + \dfrac{y\cdot e^{2b+2x}-y}{e^{2b+2x}+1}+\dfrac{w\cdot e^{2c+2x}-w}{e^{2c+2x}+1}\right)} \\- \exp{\left(-\left({\dfrac{z\cdot e^{2a+2x}-z}{e^{2a+2x}+1} + \dfrac{y\cdot e^{2b+2x}-y}{e^{2b+2x}+1}+\dfrac{w\cdot e^{2c+2x}-w}{e^{2c+2x}+1}}\right)\right)}}{\exp{\left(\dfrac{z\cdot e^{2a+2x}-z}{e^{2a+2x}+1} + \dfrac{y\cdot e^{2b+2x}-y}{e^{2b+2x}+1}+\dfrac{w\cdot e^{2c+2x}-w}{e^{2c+2x}+1}\right)}\\ + \exp{\left(-\left({\dfrac{z\cdot e^{2a+2x}-z}{e^{2a+2x}+1} + \dfrac{y\cdot e^{2b+2x}-y}{e^{2b+2x}+1}+\dfrac{w\cdot e^{2c+2x}-w}{e^{2c+2x}+1}}\right)\right)}}
\end{equation}

And I've sort of just been stuck switching this equation into different forms but never actually getting closer to solving for $x$. Another messy iteration:

\begin{equation}
\frac{z\cdot e^{2a+2x}-z}{e^{2a+2x}+1} + \frac{y\cdot e^{2b+2x}-y}{e^{2b+2x}+1} + \frac{w\cdot e^{2c+2x}-w}{e^{2c+2x}+1} = \frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{-R-1}{R-1}\right)
\end{equation}

Any ideas? I've never really dealt with hyperbolic tangents before, so I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: I bet that you will not be able to isolate $x$. Numerical methods need to be considered. Can you give a set of $a,b,c,y,w,z$ ?

Answer (score 1):

That's weird.
Why are you taking
the $\tanh$ of
the sum of $\tanh$s?

Anyway,
an obvious first step
is to rewrite it as
$\text{atanh}(R) 
=  \tanh(a+x)z + \tanh(b+x)y + \tanh(c+x)w 
$.

There isn't any formula for
$\tanh(u)+\tanh(v)
$,
so you will have to solve this numerically.

Since
$\tanh'(x)
= 1-\tanh^2(x)
$,
Newton's method would
probably work nicely.

Good luck.