# Using addition formulas brings weird results

Tags: systems-of-equations, hyperbolic-functions

So, I have this set of equation that I want to solve for x,y
$$
A = \tanh(x+y) \\
B = \tanh(x-y)
$$
and of course it can be solved by inverting and then summing/differencing, so I get
$$
x = \dfrac{1}{2}\bigg(arctanhA + arctanhB \bigg) \\
y = \dfrac{1}{2}\bigg(arctanhA - arctanhB \bigg)
$$
But what if I want to use addition formula (and I need to because this is just a short version of the equations that I have, where the above method cannot be used) writing
$$
A = \dfrac{\tanh x + \tanh y}{1+\tanh x \tanh y} \\
B = \dfrac{\tanh x - \tanh y}{1-\tanh x \tanh y}
$$
Now I get a quadratic equation for $\tanh x$ and I didn't figure out how to show that it gives the same result. I tried using identities and also plotting the two results but they are different. Here is the quadratic equation that I have:
$$
\tanh y = \dfrac{A - \tanh x}{1-A \tanh x} \\
B \bigg[ 1 - \tanh x \dfrac{A -\tanh x}{1- A\tanh x} \bigg] = \tanh x - \dfrac{A -\tanh x}{1- A\tanh x}
$$
and then finally for $\tanh x$
$$
(A+B) \tanh ^2 x -2 \tanh x(A+1)  + A+B=0
$$

Comment: Please, provide the quadratic equation you obtain: there maybe an error in the computation of its roots...

Comment: I have attempted to solve your equations using a Computer Algebra System: It is indeed awful. When you say that your first method doesn't apply for certain domain of values of $A,B$, my experience is that you can turn around the difficulty by switching between arctanh and arctan (without h). Maybe you can explain what the original problem is.

Comment: Another testimony of a bad experience with this sort of things: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2449888/305862

Comment: @JeanMarie I just added the final quadratic equation for $\tanh x$, the original problem has actually an additional term in the first equation, i.e. $ A = \tanh (x+y) + (1-p) \tanh x$. This is why I guess I'm forced to use addition formula.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\at}{\operatorname{arctanh}}$

$$B \left(1 - \tanh x \frac{A -\tanh x}{1- A\tanh x} \right) = \tanh x - \frac{A -\tanh x}{1- A\tanh x}$$

$$B \left(1-A\tanh x - \tanh x (A -\tanh x) \right) = (1- A \tanh x)\tanh x - (A -\tanh x)$$

$$B-2 A B\tanh x +B \tanh^2 x = 2\tanh x-A \tanh^2x-A$$

$$(A+B)\tanh^2x-2(1+AB)\tanh x + A+B=0$$

You made a mistake when getting the quadratic.

After solving the quadratic and some simplification

$$\tanh x =\frac{1+A B\pm\sqrt{(1-A^2)(1-B^2)}}{A+B}$$

We choose the $-$ sign because $\tanh x \in (-1,1)$, and finally

$$x =\at\left(\frac{1+A B-\sqrt{(1-A^2)(1-B^2)}}{A+B}\right)$$

Now you will be able to verify that $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\at A + \at B \right) =\at \left(\frac{1+A B-\sqrt{(1-A^2)(1-B^2)}}{A+B}\right)$$ using some of the known identities.

Comment: [+1] I find the same results. Knowing now the non-simplirfed issue, I have attempted to show that cancelling the $(1-p)\tanh x$ is maybe not the best operation to do...

Comment: In fact, using https://approach0.xyz/ I was amazed at the frequent number of times expressions like $\frac{1+A B\pm \sqrt{(1-A^2)(1-B^2)}}{A+B}$ (connected with $\operatorname{arctanh}$) or $\frac{mn-1 \pm \sqrt{(m^2+1)(n^2+1)}}{m+n}$  (connected with $\arctan$ : slopes of bissector lines) were involved...

Comment: A detail, as you have used several times '\text{arctanh}', I have shown you directly in the text of your answer how one can do it once for all by using command '$\newcommand{\at}{\operatorname{arctanh}}$'

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you! I wasn't aware that MathJax allows to define $\LaTeX$ macros. I'm going to search for other $\LaTeX$ features I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

I think your original problem with equations like

$$A = \tanh (x+y) + (1-p) \tanh x$$

is more complicated than the simplified problem.

Look at what the solutions can be (using Geogebra) for $A=0.6, B=0.3,p=0.2$ for example:

[image]

(are the equations the good ones ?).

Comment: Any comment ? ....